# Jquery Reel, first part of animation plays, the remaining part controlled

Tags: jquery

I have an image I'm trying to control using the Jquery Reel plugin.  The plug-in basically allows any sort of animation by scrolling through several images.  What's nice about it is you can control the animation by running your mouse over the image and dragging.  What I'm having a hard time with is I want the animation to be initiated by clicking the image, to then play through only a certain amount of the images and stop.  I then want the remaining image sequence to be the controlled part, preventing you from then moving back to the part that played in the beginning.

The other thing that would be awesome would be to figure out a way to somehow show the image range so literally every image didn't have to be typed in.  I tried many times to figure this out.  I can't figure out if I'm suppose to use the "opening" option, I haven't been able to make that option do anything that effects the final product.  I'm at a loss here.

This is the url to the plugin site http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel#download
and this is the url to the example I posted below http://klossal.com/reel/example/object.html

Thanks for any help I can get on this, I spent the majority of the day on this to no avail.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' content='text/html' http-equiv='Content-type' />
<title>Object Example - jQuery Reel 360Â°</title>
<link href='style/example.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='../jquery.reel-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='inc/jquery.disabletextselect-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='inc/jquery.mousewheel-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example">
<img id='image' src='/portfolio/layers/37/layers.png' width='600' height='600' />
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#image').reel({ 
opening:1.2,
loops: false,
frames: 36, 
path:    '/portfolio/layers/37/',
images:         
['00001.png','00002.png','00003.png','00004.png','00005.png','00006.png','00007.png','00008.n
g','00009.png','00010.png','00011.png','00012.png','00013.png','00014.png','00015.png','00016.
png','00017.png','00018.png','00019.png','00020.png','00021.png','00022.png','00023.png','0002  
4.png','00025.png','00026.png','00027.png','00028.png','00029.png','00030.png','00031.png','00
032.png','00033.png','00034.png','00035.png','00036.png']
}); });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```